# OpenGL(with GLSL) Cube Rendering using custom vertex data

Tags: opengl

Trying to render a cube in OpenGL desktop, but the parameters for `glVertexAttribPointer(...)` are not working for me. Requesting for suggestions to get the code working.Below is the relevant code snippet

---

```
struct vertex{
        GLfloat x,y,z;
        GLfloat tU,tV;
    };
    float dim = 1.0f;
    vertex vertexData[] = { 
        -dim, -dim,  dim, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         dim, -dim,  dim, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         dim,  dim,  dim, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -dim,  dim,  dim, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -dim, -dim, -dim, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         dim, -dim, -dim, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         dim,  dim, -dim, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -dim,  dim, -dim, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    };
    #define BUFFER_OFFSET(offset) ((void *)(offset))
    g_vertexLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vertexPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(g_vertexLocation);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(g_vertexLocation,3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    g_texCoordLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, "in_texCoord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(g_texCoordLocation);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(g_texCoordLocation,2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5, BUFFER_OFFSET(3));
GLushort indexData[] = 
    {
       0,1,2,
       0,2,3,
       1,5,6,
       1,6,2,
       2,6,7,
       2,7,3,
       0,3,4,
       3,7,4,
       4,7,5,
       5,7,6,
       1,0,4,
       1,4,5,
    };
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,indexBufferID);
    int size;
    glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &size);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size/sizeof(GLushort), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Note:The vertex shader is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer offsets are counted in bytes, so the strides and position need to be multiplied by `sizeof(float)` to be correct.

The `stride` parameter of the first `glVertexAttribPointer` call needs to be `5 * sizeof(float)` as well as your second call : the vertices components are located each `5 * sizeof(float)` of your attributes buffer.

Comment: Thanks , but still the cube is not getting rendered.More corrections are required, is the last parameter correct ?

Comment: Also I am using glDrawElements(), added the index and draw code.

Comment: No,I am filling the index buffer as well as the vertex buffer data. Things are fine if I use separate texture and vertex data arrays, but not getting how to use custom vertex data.

Comment: You didn't provide the filling code. But please see my edit !

Comment: Cube rendered ! (void*)(3*sizeof(float)) in place of BUFFER_OFFSET(3) corrected the texture !